# Calender implementaion in my application to track my events and synch on google calender

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm new in ios development and I want to create an application which synch event from google calender.
I search over google but didn't found any sample code that can help me, from where I can start my app?
Please help me out, your suggestion can be my start up point, or could be the direction for me.

Thanks in Advance.